# Paging implementation in C# using Stored Procedure (SQL 2000)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Anyone with a link to a sample code with paging that can be changed to work within a (10000+ records) table? I want to display the records on my asp.net page.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Best practice for pagination, is to do it in your stored proc, so you can limit the amount of data you are pulling back, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSomeData
  @page INT,
  @size INT = 25
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @offset INT
    SET @offset = (@page - 1) * @size;

    WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Field1) AS 'Index'
      FROM SomeTable
    )
    SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @size)
END
GO
```

That's specific to Sql Server, MySql is a little easier:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSomeData(IN page INT, IN size INT DEFAULT 25)
BEGIN
  DECLARE offset INT DEFAULT 0
  SET offset = (page - 1) * size;

  SELECT `Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3` FROM `SomeTable` LIMIT offset, (offset + size);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**, seems like you are using Sql 2000.

Pagination is a little trickier on Sql 2000, as you don't have any built in functions for generating an efficient page count.  What you could do, is create temporary table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSomeData
  @page INT,
  @size INT = 25
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @offset INT
  SET @offset = (@page - 1) * @size

  CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
    [Index] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Field1] VARCHAR(100),
    [Field2] VARCHAR(100),
    [Field3] VARCHAR(100)
  )

  INSERT INTO #temp ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3])
  SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] FROM SomeTable

  SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] FROM #temp WHERE [Index] BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @size)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCoutOfSomeData
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT
    SELECT @count = COUNT([Field1]) FROM SomeTable

    SELECT @count
END
GO
```

Not terribly efficient, but you work with what you've got.  Now, on the server side, you can create a method to get your results back, so, for example:

```
public class SomeDataSelector
{
  public IEnumerable<SomeDataType> GetSomeData(int page, int size)
  {
    List<SomeDataType> result = new List<SomeDataType>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetSomeData", conn)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            // Do work here to create instance of SomeDataType.


          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  public int GetCoutOfSomeData()
  {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetSomeData", conn)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then bind that to your ASP.NET control.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="SomeDataSelector" SelectMethod="GetSomeData" SelectCountMethod="GetCoutOfSomeData" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="Field1" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" />
```

It's not a complete solution, but should be enough to get you going.

**UPDATE** A friend of mine found an alternative article about paging in Sql 2000: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServer2KPagingSorting.aspx

Comment: How would I display that on my page? Do you have some sample code that I can run to view the data? How do I move to the next page? Thanx for your help.

Comment: What have you got so far? What are you using, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC? Are you data binding? We need more information!

Comment: I am using ASP.NET
Basically I am yet to start coding this. I have been simply doing data retrieval and showing it on my page but now I need to do a listing of all items in a table on my page. 

I am using DIV tags and not <tables>

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew, I am testing the ones you have updated.

Comment: I am retrieving data from 4 different tables. I am creating a view for that. My question is, do I load the temp table by querying the view of I can just use the view instead of the temp table?

Comment: You need to use the temp table in this solution to provide the unique index. You need the unique index to be able to select the specific page you want to return.

Comment: http://programming.top54u.com/post/AJAX-GridView-Paging-and-Sorting-using-C-sharp-in-ASP-Net.aspx



I found that link, is there a way I can modify that with the stored procedure you provided for better efficiency or it already loads it in paged format instead of querying all 10000+ records.

Answer (score 1):

I have given a complete solution in my blog [Custom Pagination Class in asp.net](http://pandiyachendur.blogspot.com/2009/11/custom-pagination-class-in-aspnet.html)... Please let me know for more details....

Comment: I am using SQL 2000. Your implementation seems to be for 2005. Is that right?

Comment: I am working using sql 2000. Do you have a solution that works for 2000?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this article in CodeProject a few years ago that explains in details on exactly how you can achieve that with complete source and example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewNeatPaging.aspx